# TypeScript: map strongly-typed collection

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a strongly-typed collection as follows:

```
interface IUser {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

const users: IUser[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
  // ...
];
```

Then, I create a new collection using the `map` function:

```
const nextUsers: IUser[] = users.map((user: IUser) => ({
  ID: 3, // wrong field name
  name: 'Mike',
  id: 3,
}));
```

As you can see, there is a field with a wrong name - `ID`. Well, the question is why does it [work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IUser%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20users%3A%20IUser%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20'Bob'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20'John'%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20nextUsers%3A%20IUser%5B%5D%20%3D%20users.map((user%3A%20IUser)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Mike'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ID%3A%20152%2C%0D%0A%7D))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(JSON.stringify(nextUsers))%3B)?))

Comment: I updated your question to reflect the actual code in the playground link. Your original code would not have worked

Comment: This is actually due to a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a byproduct of how typescript checks for excess properties. A little bit of background:

Type A is generally assignable from type B if type B has at least all the properties of type A. So for example, no error is expected when performing this assignment:

```
let someObject = { id: 3, name: 'Mike', lastName: 'Bob' }
let user: { id: number, name: string } = someObject // Ok since someobject has all the properties of user
let userWithPass : { id: number, name: string, pass: string } = someObject // Error since someobject does not have pass
```

The only time Typescript will complain about excess properties is when we try to directly assign an object literal to some object that has a known type:

```
// Error excess property lastName
let user: { id: number, name: string } =  { id: 3, name: 'Mike', lastName: 'Bob' }
```

Now in your case, typescript will first infer the type of the result to `map` to the type of the returned object literal, which is all valid, and then will check that this type is compatible with the `IUser` array which it is, so no error since we never directly tried to assign the object literal to something of type `IUser`.

We can ensure we get an error if we explicitly set the return type of the arrow function passed to `map`

```
const nextUsers: IUser[] = users.map((user: IUser) : IUser => ({
    id: 3,
    name: 'Mike',
    ID: 152,
}));
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice hint with a type of the arrow function!

Answer (score 1):

An interface defines some properties an object *must* have, but it is not exhaustive; the object can have other properties as well. This is demonstrated in the docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#our-first-interface).

Answer (score 1):

It works because the properties of the interface are defined. The interface does not prevent additional properties from being added.

However :

```
const nextUsers: IUser[] = users.map((user: IUser) => ({
  ID: 3, // wrong field name
  name: 'Mike',
}));
```

This results in an error from the TypeScript compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It stills works but if you had a typescript linter you would have an ERROR because the returned array type is different then IUse[]